# Puppeteersharp - redundant chromium command line arguments when using it in the container with .Net Core App

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, puppeteer

I have a task, that requires me of creating microservice, that uses puppeteersharp in order to make page screenshots. In order to do so, I use ASP.net core web api project template. In Startup.cs file I launch Puppeteersharp. Below is the code for that:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddControllers();

        Browser puppeteerBrowser = null;

        Task.Run(async () => puppeteerBrowser = await LaunchPuppeteerBrowserAsync());

        services.AddSingleton(puppeteerBrowser);
}

public static async Task<Browser> LaunchPuppeteerBrowserAsync()
{
        Console.WriteLine("Starting to launch CHROMIUM...");

        // Uncomment to let puppeteer download chromium
        //await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);

        var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
        {
            // Comment to let puppeteer run downloaded chromium
            ExecutablePath = "/usr/bin/chromium",

            Args = new[]{ "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu-rasterization", "--disable-remote-extensions" },

            Headless = true,

            // Didn't help
            //IgnoredDefaultArgs = new []{ "--enable-gpu-rasterization", "--enable-remote-extensions", "--load-extension=" }
        });

        Console.WriteLine("CHROMIUM launched successfully");

        return browser;
    }
```

Further, the microsevice is required to run in the container inside our server. I created dockerfile, that uses standard docker-image for .Net Core applications from dockerhub, created by Microsoft. In order to Illustrate my problem, I created test application and uploaded it to github repo, you can find it here:

[ASP.net Core Web Api project](https://github.com/tkurskiev/PuppeteerTestApp)

There is a dockerfile, which can be used to build image like so:

[image: Cmd screenshot]

*Please note, that I'm using Windows 10, and for test purposes I installed Docker onto my machine.

So, as you might know, docker images have layered structure. In order to take advantage of that feature, I decided to add the download and installation of chromium browser as 1 of the steps in dockerfile. That way, when request comes to server for the first time since launch, puppeteersharp library will not have to download the browser first and then do the job it required to do, and will use the binary (or whatever it is called in linux, I mean the application launching file; in windows that would be .exe).
You can see, that I provide executable path to Puppeteersharp browser when launching new browser in the code example I provided earlier (`ExecutablePath = "/usr/bin/chromium"`).
The container can be started the following way:

[image]

And finally, I can describe my problem. First, using CMD command: `docker exec -it e95e6d9fca63  bash` I tune into container's bash.
There I run this:

[image]

In order to "ps" command to work. I also install "less" package (`apt-get install less`).
Then I run `ps aux | less` to show running processes inside the container. I get the following result, which show the command line parameters for chromium process, how it was launched. I underlined the ones, which bother me:

[image]

```
 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --show-component-extension-options --enable-gpu-rasterization --no-default-browser-check --disable-pings --media-router=0 --enable-remote-extensions --load-extension= --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=TranslateUI,BlinkGenPropertyTrees --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --headless --hide-scrollbars --mute-audio about:blank --no-sandbox --disable-gpu-rasterization --disable-remote-extensions --remote-debugging-port=0 --user-data-dir=/tmp/kgkyt1d1.bqe
```

The latter `--disable-gpu-rasterization --disable-remote-extensions` arguments are the ones I set manually in Args property of LaunchOptions - check out the first code example I provided.
I also tried to use "IgnoredDefaultArgs" property of LaunchOptions, because according to documenation of the library, the options set there will be ignored. You can also see that happening in source code.

[Launcher code](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/blob/44bc7519cde764f7b1d552debd94f7e4a98bb5a7/lib/PuppeteerSharp/Launcher.cs#L47) - creates new chromium process, which has ["PrepareChromiumArgs" method](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/blob/44bc7519cde764f7b1d552debd94f7e4a98bb5a7/lib/PuppeteerSharp/ChromiumProcess.cs#L212)

The parameters put into "IgnoredDefaultArgs" array get deleted from the result array. But that didn't help, the `--enable-gpu-rasterization --enable-remote-extensions --load-extension=` are still there.

The strange thing is, that when I let the Puppeteersharp library to fetch the browser itself, and  comment out "ExecutablePath" property from "LaunghOptions" and start it, there are no such redundant parameters. I have checked it.

My guess is that redundant arguments occur from the executable I downloaded when it gets started by the library. I mean in somewhat similar fashion that Windows allows you to add to file properties some extra command line arguments. But is this possible in Linux?

Can anyone please help?